# Icons from fontawesome not loading on live open server?

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

How can I get the icons within the tabs section to appear on the live open server? I tried with the code below:

Loading the styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-o53vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK10YPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="netflix.css" type="text/css">
```

And here are the tabs:

```
<section class="tabs">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-item tab-border">
      <i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>
      <p class="hide-sm">Cancel at any time</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-item">
      <i class="fas fa-tablet-alt fa-3x"></i>
      <p class="hide-sm">Watch anywhere</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-item">
      <i class="fas fa-tags fa-3x"></i>
      <p class="hide-sm">Pick your price</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

fontawesome now uses <script instead of link so the link I was using was outdated. This has now been fixed to the below.